# Create a list of objects from a list of String in groovy

Tags: list, groovy, collect

I am having a list of string as follows.

```
List l = ["1","2","3"]
```

And I have a class like as follows.

```
class person {
    String name
}
```

I want to create a list of person object from List l.

I have tried using groovy list collect but I am not able to do so.

Here is my code.

```
class testJsonSlurper {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        List l = ["1","2","3"]
        def l2 = l.collect { new person(it) }
        println(l2)
    }
}
```

But I getting following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: testJsonSlurper$person(java.lang.String)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your class **testJsonSlurper**, you have to change this line

```
def l2 = l.collect { new person(it) }
```

into

```
def l2 = l.collect { new person(name:it) }
```

This is what we call **Named argument constructor**. You can find more about **Named argument constructor** [here](http://groovy-lang.org/objectorientation.html#_named_argument_constructor).

If you do not want to make this change, then you need to add constructor in class **person** yourself.
The class **person** should look like this after adding constructor.

```
​class person {    
    String name

    person(name){
        this.name = name
    }
}
```